# Disabled fields with JQuery appearing in request on C# server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, validation, razor

I am disabling some fields on the client side dynamically with JQuery. And while submitting the form they are appearing on the server side request. As far as I went through documentation it should exclude disabled input. following code disable inputs if they are empty:

```
  var partnerInputs = $('.partner.newPartner .row');
  var firstName = newPartnerInputs.find(":input[name$='.FirstName']");
  var lastName = newPartnerInputs.find(":input[name$='.LastName']");
  var emailAddress = newPartnerInputs.find(":input[name$='.EmailAddress']");
  if ($.trim(firstName.val()).length === 0 && $.trim(lastName.val()).length === 0 && $.trim(emailAddress.val()).length === 0) {
    firstName.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    lastName.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    emailAddress.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    reattachUnobtrusiveValidation($("#selectPartners"));
  }
```

and simple

```
form.submit()
```

reattachUnobtrusiveValidation method simply recalculating the validation for the form. and it is ignoring disabled fields if I am using

```
$("#form").validate().form()
```

This is posting the form to a C# controller. and the model at the server side or ven the form in JS contains the disabled fields before submitting. I went through html form post and it excludes fields which are disabled. What could be wrong here ?

Comment: Without seeing the code which causes this behaviour we can't really help you find the mistake.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can understand better what the problem is and what the solution might be.

Comment: Also the minimal code example you added isn't really useful. In isolation it will obviously disable a form field, though I don't know why you're making the same call twice. So for some reason that isn't working for you. Is there an error elsewhere in your JS which is preventing it from working? Is `field` empty or undefined? Are you running this code before the DOM has loaded? Have you included jQuery.js in the page? We don't know, and so cannot give you any useful help.

Comment: If these values are still appearing in your server side then the JS you're executing is clearly not working. Please remember that I, and others here, are trying to help you. All we need is the information to be able to do that.

Comment: People have read and understood the question. You are being downvoted as there's not enough information here to provide you with an answer. There are hundreds of reasons for the problem you describe to be happening, and without a clear example of your logic which creates the issue people will simply be wasting their time guessing.

Comment: That question is almost 10 years old, and the guidelines of this site have changed dramatically over that time to improve the quality of questions that are asked. If you haven't already I'd suggest reading them.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh I understand that it can be upsetting that your answer is getting downvoted, but there is no reason to get mad at RoryMcCrossan, he is only trying to help you, like many others will do. You have a better chance of getting upvoted and answers if you provide the community with all the information you find relative.

Comment: @Rory sorry. I will try to be careful in future while asking questions. I will try to add more info to this one

Answer (score 0):

It appears the functionality of this feature is to not post the value of the field. This can not omit the input/field from the post model but can only post the null for this field.